# How do I make my code capitalize the first letter of the word that has a capital letter in it? (Pig Latin)

Tags: python

My code so far is:

```
def to_pig(string):
    words = string.split()

    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        
        '''
        if first letter is a vowel
        '''
        if word[0] in 'aeiou':
            words[i] = words[i]+ "yay"
        elif word[0] in 'AEIOU':
            words[i] = words[i]+ "yay"
        else:
            '''
            else get vowel position and postfix all the consonants 
            present before that vowel to the end of the word along with "ay"
            '''
            has_vowel = False
            
            for j, letter in enumerate(word):
                if letter in 'aeiou':
                    words[i] = word[j:] + word[:j] + "ay"
                    has_vowel = True
                    break

            #if the word doesn't have any vowel then simply postfix "ay"
            if(has_vowel == False):
                words[i] = words[i]+ "ay"

    pig_latin = ' '.join(words)
    return pig_latin
```

My code right now coverts a string to pig latin string. If a word starts with one or more consonants followed by a vowel, the consonants up to but not including the first vowel are moved to the end of the word and "ay" is added. If a word begins with a vowel, then "yay" is added to the end.

String:
"The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plains"

However, my code returns:
"eThay ainray inyay ainSpay aysstay ainlymay inyay ethay ainsplay"

While it should return:
"Ethay ainray inyay Ainspay aysstay ainlymay inyay ethay ainsplay"

How do I fix my code so that it returns the first letter capital for the word that has a capital letter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `any(... isupper())` to check for the presence of a capital letter and `str.title()` to capitalize the first letter.

```
>>> words = "eThay ainray inyay ainSpay aysstay ainlymay inyay ethay ainsplay".split()
>>> words = [word.title() if any(c.isupper() for c in word) else word for word in words]
>>> ' '.join(words)
'Ethay ainray inyay Ainspay aysstay ainlymay inyay ethay ainsplay'
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution would be to check whether the word contains a capital letter. If so, you want to convert the capital letter to a lowercase letter and then capitalize the first letter of that word. You could do that as such. Suppose you have your array of words, then:

```py
words = [i[0].upper() + i[1:].lower() if i.lower() != i else i for i in words]
```

Comment: Hello, would I add this after my second sentence, "words = string.split()"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just before the line pig_latin = ' '.join(words)